# Implement MVVM on a Login Button in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm

I have a Qustion regarding the MVVM Pattern.
I have a page with a button. I created a LoginCommand for the Button and a ViewModel to handle the command. Now i want the button to change to a logout button if the LoginCommand is successfull.

I am just starting with MVVM so i do not know how i start handling this.

Thanks,
Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use DataTrigger on the Button. 
Depending on a property "Authenticated", button's text property can be either "Login" or "Logout".

Xaml code :

```html
<Button 
    Text="Login" 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Command="{Binding Login}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" 
                     Binding="{Binding Authenticated}" 
                     Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Text" Value="Logout" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

View model code :

```
private bool _authenticated;

    public bool Authenticated
    {
        get => _authenticated;
        set
        {
            _authenticated = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Authenticated));
        }
    }

    public ICommand Login => new Command(() =>
    {
        //Logic to authenticate user
        Authenticated = !Authenticated;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So i assume you want one button for both 'Login' and 'Logout'?

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
```

And then in your viewmodel:

```
private string _ButtonContent;
public string ButtonContent
{
    get { return _ButtonContent;?? (_ButtonContent = "Login"); }
    set
    { 
        _ButtonContent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonContent"); 
    }
 }

private ICommand _ClickCommand;
public ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get { return _ClickCommand ?? (_ClickCommand = _LoginCommand); }
    set
    {
        _ClickCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ClickCommand");
    }
 } 

private ICommand _LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(f => Login());
private ICommand _LogoutCommand = new RelayCommand(f => Logout());

private void Login()
{
    // Do your Login stuff here
    // Create if statement for when to Login is not completed succesfully
    // switch the button   
    ButtonText = "Logout";
    ClickCommand = LoginCommand;
}

private void Logout()
{
    // Do your Logout stuff here

    // switch the button   
    ButtonText = "Login";
    ClickCommand = LogoutCommand;
}
```

For this to work you need to implement [NotifyPropertyChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) so the viewmodel knows that some property changed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your button layout. If they are two different buttons, you'll want to alternate the visibility. If it's just the text, you can simply change the text property.

Below is a simple example to implement a login/logout on one button by changing the text:

XAML

```xml
<Button
    Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
    Command="{Binding OnButtonClickCommand}"/>
```

C# (ViewModel)

```cs
private bool isLoggedIn = false;

private ICommand onButtonClickCommand;
public ICommand OnButtonClickCommand => onButtonClickCommand ?? (onButtonClickCommand = new Command(OnButtonClick));

private string buttonText = "Login";
public string ButtonText
{
    get => buttonText;
    set 
    {
        buttonText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void OnButtonClick()
{
    if ((!isLoggedIn) && (Login()))
    {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        ButtonText = "Logout";
    }
    else
    {
        Logout();
        isLoggedIn = false;
        ButtonText = "Login";
    }
}
```